# What is the meaning of "Om Astraya Phat"?

Tags: mantras, rituals

I stumbled upon the "Om Astraya Phat" mantra as I was going through deity worship guidelines in ISKCON desire tree website. It hadn't mentioned the meaning of the mantra and researching on the internet also brought no results. Does anyone here know the meaning of the aforementioned mantra ?

Comment: Astraya phat is the Astra mantra. It is used during nyasas for purifying oneself before Puja/Iapa. It is also used to purify the Puja place (the ground or the floor).

Comment: It is tantric mantra used in puja